# Understanding gradient descent as an integral

Tags: optimization, gradient-descent

The update rule in gradient descent on $\mathbf w$ over cost function $J(\mathbf w)$ is given by:
$$\mathbf w_{t+1}=\mathbf w_t-\eta\nabla_{\mathbf w}J(\mathbf w_t)$$

This rule seems to integrate the signal $\nabla_{\mathbf w_t}J(\mathbf w)$ over $t$ time steps. Therefore, at convergence, is it correct to write the following equation?

$$\mathbf w_{\text{opt}} = \mathbf w_{\text{init}} -\eta\int_0^\infty \nabla_{\mathbf w}J(\mathbf w_t) \, \mathrm{d}t$$

So, does that mean if the integral term above is analytically solvable — I suspect that it is not the case in general but for simple cost functions, maybe — we can predetermine $\mathbf w_{\text{opt}}$ given the cost function and the initial position $\mathbf w_{\text{init}}$? Wouldn't it be so that in such special cases GD is not needed at all, like for example when $J$ is known to be convex/concave in the domain $\mathbf w$?

Comment: Indeed, gradient descent system was a discrete approximation of a continuous dynamic system. We can know the optimal point if the cost function is directly solvable. In such cases, there's no point of using GD.

Comment: [Related](https://mathoverflow.net/q/252963/91764)

Comment: Have you tried for, say, quadratic cost functions?

Comment: @VezenBU, That sounds like an answer to the question.  Can I encourage you to write that in the 'Your Answer' box below, so we can upvote it and the question can be considered answer?  On Stack Exchange sites we discourage writing answers to the question in the comments box (even if they are short).  Thank you for considering it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Derivative of the GD update rule with respect to $t$ can be given as:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^t}{\mathrm{d}t}=\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^{t-1}}{\mathrm{d}t}-\eta\frac{\mathrm{d}{\nabla_{\mathbf w}J(\mathbf w^{t-1})}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$
$$=\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^{t-1}}{\mathrm{d}t}-\eta\frac{\mathrm{d}{\nabla_{\mathbf w}J(\mathbf w^{t-1})}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^{t-1}}\cdot\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^{t-1}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

where $\frac{\mathrm{d}{\nabla_{\mathbf w}J(\mathbf w^t)}}{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^t}$ is the Hessian $\mathbf H_\mathbf w(t)$. Simplifying, we have:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^{t}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\left[\mathbf I-\eta\mathbf H_\mathbf w(t-1)\right]\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^{t-1}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Unrolling this over $t$ steps, we can write:
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^{t}}{\mathrm{d}t}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{t}\left[\mathbf I-\eta\mathbf H_\mathbf w(t-i)\right]\right)\frac{\mathrm{d}\mathbf w^{init}}{\mathrm{d}t}$$

Integrating with respect to $\mathrm{d}t$:
$$\mathbf w^{t}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^{t}\left[\mathbf I-\eta\mathbf H_\mathbf w(t-i)\right]\right)\mathbf w^{init}$$

$\mathbf w^{opt}$ will be found if $\lim_{t\to\infty}\mathbf w^{t}$ converges, which is
$$\mathbf w^{opt}=\left(\prod_{i=1}^\infty\left[\mathbf I-\eta\mathbf H_\mathbf w(t-i)\right]\right)\mathbf w^{init}$$
$$=\mathbf M\mathbf w^{init}$$

This shows that GD finds a linear transformation $\mathbf M$ that changes a given $\mathbf w^{init}$ to $\mathbf w^{opt}$. This also shows that the relation between $\mathbf M$ and $\mathbf w^{init}$ is unique, i.e., for a given $\mathbf w^{init}$, GD will always converge to the same $\mathbf w^{opt}$.

Furthermore, knowing $\mathbf M$ requires the knowledge of the infinite product of Hessians $\mathbf H_\mathbf w (t)$ which is analytically intractable in general. For situations where $\mathbf H_\mathbf w (t)$ can be known, an analytical solution is indeed possible. Consider for example when $J(\mathbf w) := \frac{1}{2}\|\mathbf w\|^2$, then $\mathbf H_\mathbf w (t) = \mathbf I$. In that case, the above equation simplifies to:
$$\mathbf w^{opt}=\mathbf (1-\eta)^\infty \mathbf w^{init}$$

which converges to $\mathbf 0$ for $\eta \leq 1$ and diverges otherwise.

---

If we must force the form given in OP, we can add and subtract $\mathbf w_init$ on the right side then rearrange and add an integral to obtain:

$$\mathbf w^{t}=\mathbf w^{init}-\int_0^t\frac{1-\left(\prod_{i=1}^{t}\left[\mathbf I-\eta\mathbf H_\mathbf w(t-i)\right]\right)}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t\cdot\mathbf w^{init}$$
$$=\mathbf w^{init}+\int_0^t\frac{\prod_{i=1}^{t}\left[\mathbf I-\eta\mathbf H_\mathbf w(t-i)\right]}{\mathrm{d}t}\mathrm{d}t\cdot\mathbf w^{init}$$

Thus, the integrand is actually the rate of change of the product of Hessians instead of just $\nabla_{\mathbf w}J(\mathbf w_t)$